# Adding short description below product image on product view page

Tags: cms-block

I am displaying all the existing product on a separate CMS page via top menu link and[image] i want to add a 1 or 2 line of short description above the "add to cart" button. 
How can this be done?

Please check the screenshot for better understanding the query.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the attribute `short_description` has the flag `Use in product listing` set to `Yes`, reindex everyting.
Then edit the template you are using to display the products and add this line `<?php echo $_product->getShortDescription();?>` in the `foreach` loop where in the place you want it to appear.
There should be a line like this `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product)?>` or something similar. Add your line below that.
Some styling may be required depending on your theme.